# how to declare php variable in function like this?

Tags: php, variables

How to declare php variable in function like this ?

To test my code please load page `main.php`

I try declare `$sample = $numeric;` and `echo $sample;` but not display anything.

How can i do ?

main.php

```
<?php
  include('demo.php');
  $number = '123456789';
  test($number);
?>
```

demo.php

```
<?php
  function test($numeric)
  {
    $sample = $numeric;
  }

echo $sample;
?>
```

Comment: Your echo has to be in the function!

Comment: You don't need to. `function test($numeric) { return $numeric; } $sample = test($numeric);` works just fine

Comment: @ kingkero , how to echo $sample ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your echo in `demo.php` in the function like this:

```
function test($numeric) {
    $sample = $numeric;
    echo $sample;
}
```

Or you can return the variable like this:

```
function test($numeric) {
    return $sample = $numeric;

}
```

and the echo it with the function call like this:

```
echo test($number);
```

BTW: You should get an error if you try to echo a variable out of scope! So for error reporting use this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to display your result in `demo.php` you have to be on the demo page and the scrips should look like this:

main.php:

```
<?php
  $number = '123456789';

?>
```

demo.php:

```
<?php
  include("main.php");
  function test($numeric)
  {
    return $sample = $numeric;
  }

echo  test($number);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `$sample` is not global, it is accessible only inside the function.Rather return the value you want to use and store it in a variable and use it.Do it like -

main.php

```
<?php
  include('demo.php');
  $number = '123456789';
  $result = test($number);
  echo $result;
?>
```

demo.php

```
<?php
  function test($numeric)
  {
    $sample = $numeric;
    return $sample;
  }
?>
```

Comment: @robertwertoiut sgt's answer is correct! You have to watch that the assignment of the function call and the echo statement are in the `main.php` file and the function declaration in `demo.php`!

Comment: @ Rizier123, i try but not echo anything.

Comment: @sgt, i want to echo in demo page., like my question.

Comment: @robertwertoiut you are on `main.php` but want the output on `demo.php`? If you want the echo in demo page you have to be on this page and call the function from there an echo it, but then main.php would be useless

Comment: you are assigning the value on main apge but you want to display it on demo page??

Comment: @ sgt-  Yes,i want to do that.

Comment: @robertwertoiut Then you have to include main into demo and call the function in demo!

Comment: Or use `SESSION`/`global` variables.

Comment: try session or use @Rizier123's solution

Comment: @sgt Reached my vote limit for today, but your answer is as good as my (from my perspective) So tomorrow :D +1